# How to get Page Flipper animation for next / prev pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page flipper animation for a notebook styled divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/jdell64/c1ytu8mo/2/

```js
$('#next').click(function () {
        $('#card').toggleClass('flipped');
  
  
})
```

```css
.container {
    background: lightgray;
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    perspective: 800px;
}
#card {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#card > div {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    top: 125px;
    /* backface-visibility: hidden; */
    transition: transform 1s, visibility 0.9s;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
#card.flipped .front {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
    <div id="card">
        <div class="back">Back</div>
        <div id="mid" class="mid">Middle</div>
        <div id="front" class="front">Front</div>
    </div>
</section>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<a id="back" href="#">back</a>

<a id="next" href="#">next</a>
```

The 'next' button seems to work, but it toggles the page back and forth. How would I get it to go 'next' in an endless loop, and have the previous page do the same?

Also, as an aside... I am not sure why my 'front' content has to be at the bottom.

**More info**

Based off of [this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end), I can do this:

```
$('#next').click(function () {
     myBox = $('#card')
     myBox.toggleClass('flipped');

     myBox.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
     function (e) {
         console.log('done!');
         console.log(e);
         // code to execute after transition ends
     });
 })
```

but it fires twice for some reason.

**Update** I got the 'next' button to work, but I can't figure out the back button:

http://jsfiddle.net/jdell64/u3aebu1L/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply toggle the flipped class, adding / removing would create a forth and back notion, but if you want to flip more elements, then the flipped class should stay on the card, but instead should go to the sub elements.

To answer your aside: z-index will solve reordering issues... otherwise the sub elements will simply be put over each other, thus the last one being on top.

```js
$('#next').click(function () {
    $('#card').addClass('flipped');
});

$('#back').click(function () {
    $('#card').removeClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
.container {
    background: lightgray;
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    perspective: 800px;
}
#card {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#card > div {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    top: 125px;
    /* backface-visibility: hidden; */
    transition: transform 1s, visibility 0.9s;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
#card.flipped .front {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#card .front {
    z-index: 2;
}
#card .mid {
    z-index: 1;
}
#card div {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
    <div id="card">
        <div id="front" class="front">Front</div>
        <div id="mid" class="mid">Middle</div>
        <div class="back">Back</div>
    </div>
</section>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<a id="back" href="#">back</a>

<a id="next" href="#">next</a>
```

Comment: Okay, so this is closer to what I'm trying to do. I'd like to be able to click 'next' and have it go from front to middle, then from middle to either the back page or to a cloned middle page. Is that possible? would I need to use a JS Promise?

Answer (score 0):

You should also switch the front class to the next page so the animation will always be the same because off that 'front' class

Answer (score 0):

This is future you... I found a hacky solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jdell64/u3aebu1L/

Basically, I added a `.middle` class to be for the other direction animation. I also added a `noAnimate` class to ignore animations.

```
  .container {
    background: lightgray;
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    perspective: 800px;
}
#card {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#card > div {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 50%;
    //background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    top: 125px;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
#card .front {
    transition: transform 1s, visibility 0.9s;
}
#card .middle {
    transition: visibility 0.1s, transform 1s;
}
#card.flipped .front {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#card.flopped .middle {
    transform: rotateX(-360deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.noAnimate {
    -moz-transition-property: none !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
    -o-transition-property: none !important;
    transition-property: none !important;
}
.front {
    background: lightgreen;
}
.middle {
    background: lightblue;
}
.back {
    background: goldenrod;
}
```